# Error sending files to server aws s3 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.4

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon s3 server, I followed the Laravel 5.4 documentation that talks about FileSystems. But it returns the error:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/comercio-urbano?prefix=myfile.txt%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/test', 'TesteController@teste');
```

**Controller**

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],
```

.ENV

```
AWS_KEY=BKBAJKD62Y324W4T7QUA (
AWS_SECRET=tbG3prt8vrXp5leUp5S65xbak08ZrLBZPNdO+fbC
AWS_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=comercio-urbano
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I am no expert in laravel but a little bit of googling always helps. I guess you can get good pointers here - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate?page=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XAMPP on Windows, you need to download [certificate](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) and add it to `php.ini`:

```
curl.cainfo = "[path_to_certificate]\cacert.pem"
```

Then restart XAMPP (or Apache).